# $('#sname').html(result); what is mean this line

Tags: jquery

I don't understand what is mean by result in inside html function attribute.

what is meaning below line

```
 $('#sname').html(result);
```

Comment: `result` is most likely a variable containing some sort of HTML or text. So you replace the current HTML of `sname` with the value of `result`

Answer (score 1):

The `html()` method sets or returns the content (`innerHTML`) of the selected elements.

For example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("p").html("Hello <b>world!</b>");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Change content of all p elements</button>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the result is variable or any default attribute

Comment: result is variable which is already defined somewhere in your code.